# OPTIONS request made prior to DELETE is not ignored by java spring, unlike POST,GET

Tags: java, spring, http

I have a spring backend, which ignores `OPTIONS` request methods:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
        throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth/**");
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}
```

It works for GET and POST requests fine (i.e. it doesn't return 403 Forbidden response because of receiving initial OPTIONS requests):

```
  const request = axios({
    url: deleteEndpoint,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }); // [1]
```

When I change the method to DELETE:

```
  const request = axios({
    url: deleteEndpoint,
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
```

I get this error :

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I added `web.ignoring` of `OPTIONS` requests to my web security config in order not to receive this error message, and it works for all requests except for DELETE.

Why does this happen ? Why OPTIONS request made prior to a DELETE request is not ignored, but OPTIONS request made prior to a POST and GET are ignored?

**Update 1**
I have a custom CORS policy as below:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .exposedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type");
}
```

**[1]** As you can guess this "actualy" fails because I don't expect a POST call for a delete endpoint, what matters is that it reaches the REST endpoint and fails because of not having the expected payload.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Not to receive the 403 forbidden error, just like what I get back by making POST, GET requests.

Comment: Where is a `DELETE` request made at code at Question?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Is the `Authorization` header correct? Where is the `OPTIONS` request actually made?

Comment: Yes, it is, and it works fine for POST, GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new global cors policy. By default all origins and GET, HEAD and POST methods are allowed. Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
            .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
            .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
            .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }

}
```

Refer https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework for more details

Comment: I updated my post, I already have a cors policy in place, how come it's working for POST and GET and not for DELETE ?

Comment: By default all origins and GET, HEAD and POST methods are allowed, so I guess you need to mention .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE, "GET", "POST", "HEAD") within your CORS policy

Comment: that's right, I added `.allowedMethods("*");` and now it's accepting DELETE, too.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I only changed my CORS policy to the following:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .exposedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type")
        .allowedMethods("*"); // <--- added this line
}
```

and as @gargkshitiz mentioned in his answer, the default methods allowed does not include "DELETE" so you have to either allow it explicitly or allow all types. As I'm going to use it only for development, I allowed it for all request types.